# Why RelatedObjectDoesNotExist comes even after successful migration in pythonanywhere?

Tags: django, django-models, pythonanywhere

I know similar question asked, but in my case am getting RelatedObjectDoesNotExist after deployment to [pythonanywhere.com](http://pythonanywhere.com).

**"RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no eisfiles."**

However same codes works fine in local machine.

Model.py

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class gwDashboard(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    htmlname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.htmlname

class userInformation(models.Model):
    user =  models.ForeignKey(User)
    DbName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    DbTable = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class eisfiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    htmlname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meterId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    esiid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    metermultiplier = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    DbName = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='800WILCREST')
    DbTable = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.htmlname
    def __str__(self):
        return self.DbName
class Member(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    FIRST_NAME = models.CharField('First name', max_length=50)
    LAST_NAME = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=50)

# Using multi table inheritance - automaticly creates one to one field
class MemberDetail(Member):
    DATE_OF_BIRTH = models.DateField('Date of birth')
    EMAIL = models.EmailField('E-mail')
    PHONE = models.CharField('Phone', max_length=15)
```

**Views.py**

```
def home(request):
userName = request.user
u = User.objects.get(username=userName);
DbName=u.eisfiles   //THIS LINE OF CODE THROWS ERROR
   try:
    DbName=u.eisfiles   //THIS LINE OF CODE THROWS ERROR
    DbName=u.eisfiles.DbName
    direct=''


    return render_to_response(
    'registration/result.html',
    { 'kWhHeatMap': kWhHeatMap, 'temHeatMap':temHeatMap,"histKwhChart":histKwhChart,'officeBuilding':officeBuilding},
    )
except User.eisfiles.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
   pass
   return render_to_response(
   'registration/result.html',
   { 'kWhHeatMap': "", 'temHeatMap':"","histKwhChart":"",'officeBuilding':""},
   )
# except User.AttributeError:
#    return HttpResponse('something went wrong!! try again')
finally:
    pass
```

Comment: So, that user does not have a related eisfiles object. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have done migration correct, but why u.eisfiles line of code throws error

Comment: Because *that particular user* has no data defined for the related object.

Comment: @DanielRoseman tell me how can add data for that particular user, when I ran it locally,I just executed migration files. Do you want me to post that migration file

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check if the user you're attempting to retrieve actually exists.

```
userName = request.user # ??? This is the user object not the username
u = User.objects.get(username=userName)
```

There appears to be a problem with your query.Try this instead:

```
user = request.user
u = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
DbName = u.eisfiles.DbName
```

Comment: in eisfiles table there is no data, not sure why? I have linked properly in migration files

Comment: You never created any. How else will the table be populated

Comment: tell me how to create it?

Comment: Use the `create` method of the `manager`: `eisfiles.objects.create(user=user, ...)`. Pass the other parameters as required. Where to perform this is entirely up to you.